# AlarmManager doesn't start an service

Tags: android, android-service

I got an BroadcastReceiver which contains the following code:

```
package de.my.app;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context,AlarmService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 10000;

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Log.e("RECEIVER", "WORKS");
    }
}
```

In my log the log message of the Receiver shows up, but the message from the service doesn't show up.
If it would work fine it would show up every 10 seconds.
This is my AlarmService class:

```
package de.my.app;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class AlarmService extends IntentService {


    public AlarmService(
    ) {
        super("AlarmService");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("SERVICE","WORKS");
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("restart"));
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.my.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <permission
        android:name="de.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="de.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="Einstellungen">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.my.app.MyActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.hmkcode.android.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="restart" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".AlarmService" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: please post complete code for both clases ie of Activity or fragment where receiver is register and AlarmService

Comment: try to add log instead of toast and see if it displaying in logcat

Comment: @Shaz added my manifest

Comment: @sunil replaced the toast. As aspected it works fine for the receiver, but the service does nothing.

Comment: please post all code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am doing this way

```
//class ScheduledServiceDemoActivity
public class ScheduledServiceDemoActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PollReceiver.scheduleAlarms(this);

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.alarms_scheduled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
         .show();
    finish();
  }
}



//class PollReceiver
public class PollReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final int PERIOD=30000; // 30sec
  private static final int INITIAL_DELAY=5000; // 5 seconds

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
    if (i.getAction() == null) {
      WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(ctxt, ScheduledService.class);
    }
    else {
      scheduleAlarms(ctxt);
    }
  }

  static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {
    AlarmManager mgr=
        (AlarmManager)ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i=new Intent(ctxt, PollReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0);

    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                     SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + INITIAL_DELAY,
                     PERIOD, pi);

  }
}

//class  ScheduledService
public class ScheduledService extends WakefulIntentService {


  public ScheduledService() {
    super("ScheduledService");
  }

  @Override
  protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {

    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "I ran!"); // will run after 30 sec


  }
}
```

//mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="ScheduledServiceDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="PollReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="ScheduledService">
        </service>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `getBroadcast(...)` in the following line...

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```

...you should be using `getService(...)`.

Simply put - if you want a `PendingIntent` to be used for an `Activity`, `Service` or a `Broadcast`, you need to use the correct method depending on which type of app component it is.

Try...

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```